# iPhone Referring to Resources in Separate Directories

Tags: iphone, resources, bundle, directory-structure

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094890/separate-directory-for-iphone-resources) tells how one can create directories in your resources path. Once created, how does one reference these directories?

I have created an html directory with a structure for my internal pages, now I want to load the index.html file from the html directory. Thus, I'll need the file path to it.

I can just use:

```
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" 
                                                     ofType:@"html"];
```

But what happens if there are two index.html files contained in the directory structure? Does it just find the first one? Can the referencing be more specific?

Little test project [here](http://sites.google.com/site/iphoneappcoder/sample-projects/HTMLViewer.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) that is not working if you want to take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a path that is copied into your resource bundle, you also should reference the path when looking for the resource like:

```
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"html/index" ofType:@"html"];
```

EDIT:

You cannot apparently just include the directory in the resource name (I believe you can for other similar calls like "imageNamed:" on UIImage).  The working call is:

```
NSString *helpFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"];
```

Comment: Then `index.html` isn't in the `html` folder.

Comment: added a sample project to the question that the reference is failing in. i definitely have an index.html in the html directory. i must be doing something else a bit silly. have a look at the app delegate applicationDidFinishLaunching (where im doing the load)

Comment: Using the sample project I figured out what was going on - see revised answer.