# Keeping directory structure when creating frameworks in xcode

Tags: xcode, frameworks, header, directory-structure

I'm trying to create a framework in **Xcode** and have successfully done so, but as it turns out, **Xcode** flattens the directory structure of when copying headers in the **Copy Headers** build phase. I've tried adding the files as Folder References instead of the groups, but then it won't even recognize the header-files as header files!

So, how can I tell **Xcode** to keep the directory structure when copying the header files to my .framework-bundle?

Answer (score 14):

Use **Copy Files** instead of **Copy Headers** in the Build Phases UI.

Create a separate **Copy Files** (Editor -> Add Build Phase) for each output folder needed.

Comment: Great, this works! But the answer needs more details. I found that *Destination* needs to be set to *Wrapper* and *Subpath* must be (or begin with) `Headers` if you want the header files to be copied into the framework's public headers folder or a subfolder thereof.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot use a *folder reference* because the folders contain non-header-files, too, which you don't want to copy, add a **Run Script** build phase instead:

```
cd "${SRCROOT}/path/from/project/root/to/headers"

echo 'Copying headers into Framework..'
for H in `find . -name "*.h"`;  do
    echo "copying ${H} to ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/${H}"
    ditto "${H}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH}/${H}"
done
```

That will copy all `.h` files from the path you `cd`'d to into `YourFramework.framework/Versions/A/Headers` just like marking them as public would.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. I have .hpp file too also so I modified my the script like this `find . -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp"`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not currently a built in feature of xcode, so you must revert to scripts to copy files recursively (presumably selecting only header files): [How can I preserve subgroups when changing role to public in Copy Headers build phase in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071425/how-can-i-preserve-subgroups-when-changing-role-to-public-in-copy-headers-build)

Here's a discussion about how to accomplish just that: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/259185-copy-headers-that-preserves-subdirectory-structure.html

Answer (score 1):

Add source folder as reference to folder (radio button in the "Add files..." dialog). Then drag'n'drop those folders from Navigator tab to "Build Phases->Copy Files". 
After this headers will be located in folders on  next build.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094890/separate-directory-for-iphone-resources/) accepted answer:

> Right click on Resources, add existing files, choose your directory
>   and select "Create Folder References for any added folders".