# How can I preserve subgroups when changing role to public in Copy Headers build phase in XCode?

Tags: xcode, build, header, copy, phase

currently, the hierarchy is flattened out, and all the headers files are copied into a single Headers directory, no matter what subfolder they were in, in my Classes folder.

This is a problem when referencing the headers, if the headers have "include" statements that reference other headers in subfolders.

in particular, this screws up BridgeSupport compilation.

Comment: I think you should give an example of a header and a second header which is includes, and also any errors that are produced.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is the Copy Headers behavior always flattens the file structure. You can either add a custom file copy or a custom script at the end of the process that copies (cp -r) the headers from their original location to your desired destination. These are viable workarounds for now. Meanwhile, definitely post your request to [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: Thanks Scott; I guess a custom script will have to do for now.  I'll cross-post on Apple's bug reporting site as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Add source folder as reference to folder (radio button in the "Add files..." dialog). Then drag'n'drop those folders to "Build Phases->Copy Files". 
After this headers will be located in folders on  next build.

Answer (score 0):

From http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Oct/msg00162.html

"Try adding the folder containing the header to Xcode as a folder reference, and then add that to the Copy Headers build phase (you'll probably have to drag-drop it into the phase rather than checking the checkbox in the detail view).  Folder references are the mechanism Xcode provides for preserving a directory hierarchy during a copy."