# Creating framework in Xcode with headers in different paths

Tags: c++, xcode, frameworks, header, include

I made my own framework and saw that my test application could load the headers like

```
#include <global.h>
```

The problem is that this global.h has some more includes that are for instance in

```
<lol/head.h>
```

referring to the global.h. So the problem is that xcode cannot find those kind of headers, because when i create the framework, in the Target, my Copy Headers build phase has all the headers at the same level (the level of global.h) (all in the same folder in the framework).

Anyone can help me out on this? :) thks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found this other post with the the same question and some answers.

[Keeping directory structure when creating frameworks in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807241/keeping-directory-structure-when-creating-frameworks-in-xcode)

what i did was: create a run script copying the headers from the "base" directory to new folders inside that base directory. Now all the includes work fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can include path where all the headers are placed.

Comment: hum.. dont know if i get what you're saying, but i got my answer in another post. Gonna post it here.