# iOS - Header File notation error for Keeping Directory Structure in frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, header, frameworks, directory-structure

**Problem Background :**

I have made my own library in C++ with its respective .h and .cc files. They are organized in a small directory structure as shown :

```
.trillBPP
├── BPSK
│   ├── finddata.cc
│   ├── finddata.h
│   ├── trigger.cc
│   └── trigger.h
├── config.h
├── config_msvc.h
├── miscfunc.cc
├── miscfunc.h
└── vector
    ├── binary.cpp
    ├── binary.h
    ├── mat1.cpp
    ├── mat1.h
    ├── misc.cpp
    ├── misc.h
    ├── sort.h
    ├── vec.cpp
    └── vec.h
```

The header files in C++ are included simply with a call like - `#include <trillBPP/vector/vec.h>` or `#include <trillBPP/config.h>` depending on the ,file name and directory.

**Problem Statement :**

I'm porting this C++ code and I'm trying to create a framework in **Xcode** but as it turns out, Xcode flattens the directory structure and gives an error for the header file calls, the error that it gives says `trillBPP/vector/vec.h file not found`.
This is how the project looks like :

[image]
I've tried adding the files as *Folder References* instead of *groups*, but then it won't even recognize the header-files as header files! In *Header Search Paths* in *Build Settings*, I've also added `-I` and `/`, with no success. I came across the answer [Keeping directory structure when creating frameworks in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807241/keeping-directory-structure-when-creating-frameworks-in-xcode) , but that didn't help out because of less details for me since I'm an **Xcode** newbie.

So, ***1.*** Without changing the header file call how can I tell **Xcode** to keep the directory structure in the final framework,  ***2.*** and also keep the header file calls the same?

Comment: No comments/updates. This seems like a common issue to me which should have a solution.