# How to return multiple results from Asynchronous method?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, callback

**Note**: This question doesn't have anything to do with the language used, i.e, Swift/ Objective-C

I can't seem to get my head around how such a problem can be solved.
How an asynchronous method which processes data continuously ,return back these processed values to a function?

**Example Class structure of -> ClassName**

1. A method named `-(void)infoCallBack` , this is the method you have to call to get returns continuously.
2. Inside `-(void)infoCallBack` -> an asynchronous method `[self startRecording]`is there, which does audio recording asynchronously using AudioQueues by using a *callback method* `void AudioInputCallback(..param..)`.
3. Finally Inside `void AudioInputCallback(..param..)` -> a method `-(void) processAudio` is there, which continuously processes data and gives us an **integer number**.

How to call a method like `[ClassName infoCallBack]` in such a way that we keep getting all these processed integers continuously?

---

**Edit :** I have searched SO, and came across **completion handler blocks** : although completion handlers only return a value once after `completionHandler()` is called. Moreover, another problem in this method was how to pass around this `completionHandler` to multiple methods in the className Structure as shown.

I came across **delegates**, it said that when distinct values are being returned continuously and state of something changes, then we should call a delegate. But I was stuck at how I would return values after I call the function infoCallBack from ClassName, i.e, `[ClassName infoCallBack]` which continuously can feed the person calling this function with the values being processed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't completely understand your question but I will give you the answer in my understanding

In my opinion, you can use block to handle process update.

```
typedef void (^ProcessHandlerBlock) (NSInteger i);

- (void)infoCallBackWithProcessHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block {
  [self startRecordingWithProcessHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block];
}

- (void)startRecordingWithProcessHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block {
  [self audioInputCallbackWithParam1:@"1" param2:@"2" processHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block];
}

- (void)audioInputCallbackWithParam1:(id)param1 param2:(id)param2 processHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block {
  [self processAudioWithProcessHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block];
}

- (void)processAudioWithProcessHandlerBlock:(ProcessHandlerBlock)block {
  // Assume this is your process method callback
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.f repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
    // After receive integer, pass it to block.
    block(1);
  }];
}
```

When you want to use them, call

```
[self infoCallBackWithProcessHandlerBlock:^(NSInteger i) {
  NSLog(@"%l", i); // Do whatever you want here
}];
```

Inside the completion block of `infoCallBackWithProcessHandlerBlock` method, you can use result integer to do what you want.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, although it doesn't give a complete insight, but thank you. I'll explain in a better manner . 
My asynchronous function does recording and keeps processing the recording and continuously computes values. As soon as it computes a value I want it to return this value.

Now , it can't be done with a completion handler because it just doesn't compute one value and returns it and stops there. It keeps computing and returning many values.

Comment: @ShivanshJagga i have updated my answer, you can check again

Comment: Hi I will give the correct answer in a while. I finally got it using delegate. However, I'll still look forwardif there is a completionHandler solution. I'll post it and edit out my question after a few hours.

Comment: @ShivanshJagga you should check it. I tried and `block` called each second. I am very eager to see an answer with `delegate` ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I can't seem to get my head around how such a problem can be solved.

From the rest of what you've written I suspect you can get your head around this, you probably just need a rest. You've found the answer already without realising...

> I have searched SO, and came across completion handler blocks : although completion handlers only return a value once after completionHandler() is called.

The phrase "completion handler block" might be written as "a block used as a completion handler" - a block is just a block, you can call it as many times as needed, store it in variables, etc. While a *completion handler* is typically only called once a, say, *result reporter* might be called multiple times.

> Moreover, another problem in this method was how to pass around this completionHandler to multiple methods in the className Structure as shown.

A block is a kind of object and like other objects your class *instance* might need to use in many methods it doesn't need to be passed around but can be stored in an *instance variable*. For ease of use first declare your a shorthand for the block type, say:

```
typedef void (^SampleHandler)(int i);
```

then declare a suitable instance variable:

```
@implementation ClassName
{
   SampleHandler mySampleHandler;
}
```

now use this like any other instance variable - initialise it (mySampleHandler = ...;`), use it to call the block (`mySampleHandler(42);`)

> I came across **delegates**, it said that when distinct values are being returned continuously and state of something changes, then we should call a delegate. But I was stuck at how...

Blocks and delegates are often used for similar purposes, you can use either to solve your problem in essentially the same way - store the block/delegate reference in an instance variable, call the block/delegate method to return a value. You just have to decide which suits your use case best:

- A *block* is a *function*. A block is created *inline*, usually at the call site, and can reference (and sometimes modify) variables in the environment where it is created. Like any function it is (usually) a single-operation thing - pass argument(s), produce a side-effect/return a result.

  - A *delegate* is an *object*. Like any other object it requires an interface/implementation. Like any object it can have multiple methods, so its a multi-operation thing.

In your case - returning a value - a block is probably the best option, but you need to decide.

HTH

Comment: I wish I could up vote you multiple times. You were right, I needed rest. and I did get the right  answer which I'll be posting soon enough. :)
Also, I'll be grateful if you could help with this, people upvoted, so I'm guessing it's a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278081/ios-header-file-notation-error-for-keeping-directory-structure-in-frameworks